# Consume webservices - Return async json

Tags: c#, json, asynchronous, async-await, ashx

I currently have a search engine that calls a bunch of webservices and APIs and returns puts everything into a database.

What I want to do, is to make a async json service, that searches all the webservices and APIs and returns partial results.

The idea is, that the frontend code keeps pinging the service each second, until a "completed: true" is returned in the header.

Example pseudo-code:

```
Pull 1:
completed: false;
results, count: 2;

Pull 2:
completed: false;
results, count: 9;

Pull 3:
completed: true;
results, count: 15;
```

How do I create this the best way?
I have all my integrations as class-library projects.

My thinking was to create an ashx handler, with the IHttpAsyncHandler, but I can't seem to find anything that does what I need.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.
I use VS2013 and .NET 4.5.1, so I have all the async-await goodies to my using, if needed.

EDIT:
The server is to handle multiple request, based on a search ID, so - If the search ID is 721, it's getting the results from the 721 search, the 812 gets the ones from 812 and so on.

Comment: You could use the `Async/Await` pattern in the front end to keep pinging the service in the background.

Comment: My frontend is made in ColdFusion, so..
I have no problem in making a service, but I cannot get it to post the partial async results.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/), it sounds like exactly what you need.

Comment: Well, I don't know if SignalR will work, I've had a brief look at it.
I just need a small piece of sample, so that I can see how to get the async, partial results.

Comment: ASP.NET Web API can paginate JSON data with OData syntax support - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2013/02/19/paging-with-asp-net-web-api-odata.aspx